# Token name not displayed after deployment

Tags: erc-20, contract-deployment

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract MyContract {
address public arbDestination; // Declare arbDestination as a public address variable

function setArbDestination() external {
    arbDestination = 0x567748311B920A4c5d36eeC62Bc984d3f4a31063; // Assign a value to arbDestination
}
}

contract SEC is ERC20 {
using Address for address payable;

address private liquidityProvider;
uint256 private lockDuration;
uint256 private lockEndTime;
mapping(address => bool) private exceptionList;
uint256 private tokenPrice;
IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswapRouter;
address private uniswapPair;
address private arbDestination; // Declare arbDestination as an address variable
address private priceUpdater;
address private linkedWallet;

// Event to emit when the token price is updated
event TokenPriceUpdated(uint256 newPrice);

// Modifier to restrict access to the price update function
modifier onlyPriceUpdater() {
    require(msg.sender == priceUpdater, "Only the price updater can call this function.");
    _;
}

constructor() ERC20("SEC", "SEC") {
    _mint(msg.sender, 100000000 * 10**decimals());
    liquidityProvider = msg.sender;
    lockDuration = 30 days; // Set the lock duration to 30 days (can be adjusted as desired)
    lockEndTime = block.timestamp + lockDuration; // Calculate the end time for the lock
    tokenPrice = 5000000000000; // Set the token price to 0.000005 dollars (in wei)

    address _uniswapRouter = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D; // Uniswap V2 Router 02 address

    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouter);
    uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapRouter.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapRouter.WETH());

    priceUpdater = 0x567748311B920A4c5d36eeC62Bc984d3f4a31063; // Set the desired address as the price updater
}

modifier onlyLiquidityProvider() {
    require(msg.sender == liquidityProvider, "Only the liquidity provider can call this function.");
    _;
}

modifier notLocked() {
    require(block.timestamp >= lockEndTime || exceptionList[msg.sender], "Token is locked and cannot be swapped back to Arbitrum at the moment.");
    _;
}

modifier onlyLinkedWallet() {
    require(msg.sender == linkedWallet, "Only the linked wallet can call this function.");
    _;
}

function setLiquidityProvider(address provider) external onlyLiquidityProvider {
    liquidityProvider = provider;
}

function provideLiquidity(uint256 amount) external onlyLiquidityProvider {
    require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0.");
    _mint(liquidityProvider, amount);
}

receive() external payable {
    swapETHForTokens(msg.value);
}

function swapTokensForETH(uint256 amount) internal {
    require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0.");
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapRouter.WETH();

    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapRouter), amount);

    uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amount,
        0,
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}

function swapETHForTokens(uint256 amount) internal {
    require(amount > 0.05 ether, "Amount must be greater than 0.");

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = address(this);

    uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amount}(
        0,
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp + 360
    );
}

function setException(address account, bool status) external onlyLiquidityProvider {
    exceptionList[account] = status;
}

function unlockTokens() external {
    require(block.timestamp >= lockEndTime, "Tokens are still locked.");
    exceptionList[msg.sender] = true;
}

// Function to update the token price
function updateTokenPrice(uint256 newPrice) external onlyPriceUpdater {
    tokenPrice = newPrice;
    emit TokenPriceUpdated(newPrice);
}

function claimTokens() external notLocked {
    uint256 balance = balanceOf(msg.sender);
    require(balance > 0, "You have no tokens to claim.");

    _burn(msg.sender, balance);
    swapTokensForETH(balance);
}

// Implementation of the ERC20 token name
function name() public pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "SEC";
}

// Implementation of the ERC20 token symbol
function symbol() public pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "SEC";
}

// Implementation of the ERC20 token decimals
function decimals() public pure override returns (uint8) {
    return 18; // Adjust the number of decimals as per your token requirements
}
}
```

So a couple of issues I’m having is one the fact that after deployment the token details are not displayed.

Here is the etherscan link to the contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x06627218f5319c6eac76aa124fd27abfe8628cec

Answer (score 0):

The bytecode of the contract you deployed is way too short to be an ERC20 contract, you deployed something else (i assume `MyContract`, what is that supposed to be, btw?)

---

You're deploying

```
contract MyContract {
address public arbDestination; // Declare arbDestination as a public address variable

function setArbDestination() external {
    arbDestination = 0x567748311B920A4c5d36eeC62Bc984d3f4a31063; // Assign a value to arbDestination
}
}
```

Not the contract under it (the actual token contract you're talking about). My question is, why does this one exist at all in the first place?

Comment: It is mean to be an erc-20 contract code for a token called SEC

Comment: Clarified in an edit

Comment: I’ve resolved it, thank you.